# problemas con paginacion en php y postgres

Tags: php

tengo un error al intentar crear una paginacion para la consulta de usuarios registrados en una sistema web, al momento de generar la consulta para obtener el numero de filas de la tabla me da este error

> Warning: PDOStatement::fetch() expects parameter 1 to be int, string given in C:\xampp\htdocs\inparques\controlador\admin\controlador_consultar_admin.php

que seria esta parte del codigo en especifico

```
$total_usuarios = $conexion->query('SELECT COUNT(*) AS total FROM usuarios');
$total_usuarios = $total_usuarios->fetch("total");
```

aqui les dejo todo el codigo, aun soy novato por lo cual no logro entender que hice mal, si alguien es tan amable de explicarme mi error lo agradecia o directamente mostrarme como debo hacerlo

```
try {
    $conexion = new PDO('pgsql:host=localhost;dbname=inparques', 'postgres', '1234');
} catch (PDOException $e) {
    echo "error" . $e->getmessage();
    die();
}

$pagina = isset($_GET['pagina']) ? (int)$_GET['pagina'] : 1 ;
$postPorPagina = 1;

$inicio = ($pagina > 1) ? ($pagina * $postPorPagina - $postPorPagina) : 0 ;

$usuarios_consultados = $conexion->prepare("SELECT * FROM usuarios LIMIT $postPorPagina OFFSET $inicio");

$usuarios_consultados->execute();
$usuarios_consultados = $usuarios_consultados->fetchAll();

// print_r($usuarios_consultados);

if (!$usuarios_consultados)
{
    header('location: controlador_consultar_admin.php');
}

$total_usuarios = $conexion->query('SELECT COUNT(*) AS total FROM usuarios');
$total_usuarios = $total_usuarios->fetch("total");

print_r($total_usuarios);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ya que estás usando una función de agregación `COUNT()` entonces cambia el uso de `fetch()` por el de `fetchColumn()`; la cual va a devolver una sola fila la cual será la columna caludada de tu conteo; viendose así tu consulta:

```
$total_usuarios = $conexion->query('SELECT COUNT(*) AS total FROM usuarios');
$total_usuarios->execute();

echo $total_usuarios->fetchColumn();
```

**Anexo**

Ahora si quieres seguir manteniendo el uso del método `fetch()` considera agregar dentro de los paréntesis del mismo la constante **`PDO::FETCH_ASSOC`** lo cual va a generar que la salida que será una única fila venga en forma de **`clave => valor`** y entonces puedas recuperar el conteo total de las filas por medio del alias que indicaste el cual es **`total`** quedando así:

```
$total_usuarios = $conexion->query('SELECT COUNT(*) AS total FROM usuarios');
$total_usuarios->execute();

$data = $total_usuarios->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

echo $data["total"];
```

**Referencias**

- [PDO fetchColumn](https://www.php.net/manual/es/pdostatement.fetchcolumn.php)
- [PDO fetch](https://www.php.net/manual/es/pdostatement.fetch.php)